# Converting image coordinates from/to Latitude/Longitude representation in Robinson Projection

Tags: algorithm, math, dictionary, coordinates, projection

I have an image with a world map (displaying world in Robinson projection) and I need to find a corresponding coordinate (x/y) using latitude/longitude and vice versa.
For some reason I managed to find implementations for other projections but not Robinson. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Did you look at [Proj.4](http://trac.osgeo.org/proj/)? It includes source code for a Robinson projection but I have no idea how to decipher the macros; but for what it's worth, it's [here](http://trac.osgeo.org/proj/browser/trunk/proj/src/PJ_robin.c?rev=2311).